# Why explorer does not create a cookie when backend sends a http package with set-cookie header?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, setcookie

backend by NodeJS:

```
async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.set('Set-Cookie','name=fromBackEnd;max-age=303003030;Domain=http://localhost:8080;path=/');
    ctx.response.type = 'application/json';
    ctx.response.body = await query.menu({where: {...tool.parseUrl(ctx.request.url), flag: 0}})
}
```

open localhost in explorer:
[image: screenshot]

However cookie is not created:

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Perhaps because you are sending a nonsense value for the `Domain` parameter …?

Comment: @04FS I tried domain=localhost:8080; and not setting domain. Both failed...

Comment: Cookies are not bound to specific ports, `localhost` would be the correct value here. IE however can be picky when it comes to cookies, and “domains” that don’t include at least one period. Try and set up a local development domain, `test.local` or something like that, and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @04FS ummm...  I'm afraid I can not get you point....  what is a local development domain?

Comment: The same as “real” domain set up on your live web server - only locally, on your development machine. (`localhost` basically is one already - just with a name that can be problematic regarding such issue as f.e. cookies in IE.)